# Alfresco File Upload forms in a Share dashlet

Tags: file-upload, share, alfresco

I'm sometimes working on Alfresco dashlets that need a file-upload functionality. Instead of making stuff up, I want to use the YUI Uploader provided by Alfresco. For new pages that I build, it's easy, just list the components and put them in the page template. But for dashlets, I always have to put the upload components in the dashboard-1-column*, dashboard-2*... etc, in all of the dashboards.

I think that this is a needless HTML on a page, especially for those sites or users that don't use the dashlet in question.

Is there a neat way to include Alfrescos' file-upload forms (classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/upload/* components) only in a dashlet?

Comment: Can you share your HTML snippet your adding to the page?

Comment: The point is that I am not. I am adding the forms to the page template directly.